# Configuring Nginx to use 1 PHP script for all URLs

Tags: nginx

This must be covered somewhere but I am having trouble finding it.

I have a script named **user.php** which I want to be available at a bunch of urls, like so:

```
http://example.com/user/john
http://example.com/user/1234566
```

etc.

I put it into a directory like so:

```
/home/webroot/example.com/user/index.php
```

But I don't know how to make Nginx ignore the extended path info and still serve the /user/index.php file.

Comment: The question you are asking is a little unclear, can you explain it more and illustrate with the nginx configuration related to those specific folders (omitting server sensitive information if exists)

Comment: I have no configuration set, just the default config that Nginx provides. I just don't know how to create a config that will serve the same index.php (in a given directory) file to ALL urls (in a given directory)

Comment: Please carify.  Do you want things like `/user/john` to be redirected to `/index.php?user=john`?  What is it exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: I want someone going to /user/john to still see /user/john in their URL bar, but behind the scenes, a script located at index.php will handle EVERY request that starts with /user/ - a good example is how user pages work on SA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, which passes 'john' or '1234566' as id in your examples to your php script.

```
location ~ /user/(.*)$ {
    try_files /user/index.php?id=$1 =404;
    include fastcgi_php_params;
}
```

Adapted from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20059291/1666415

Comment: Looks like it should work, but doesn't seem to. I also tried it by setting the second line to just user.php?id=$1 instead of the /user/inde.... file, but that doesn't work. I'll keep looking, maybe I'm putting this in the wrong place of the config file (I'm putting it near the top)

Comment: See if removing the ~ from the location line gets it working.  I'm not sure if it's supposed to be there in your case.

Comment: Nope, still get a 404. I also tried with a caret, as in the page you linked, but nothing.

Comment: I wonder if there's some way to log what that block is looking for when it executes

Comment: Check /var/log/nginx/

Comment: The error log only shows 404s. But if I change that code to 403, it will give me a 403 instead.

Comment: (So I can tell that it IS doing something on the line, it just isn't finding my /user.php script that I am trying

Comment: Ahhh hmm if I just put the user.php in there without the ?id=$1 then it DOES work (although it does not parse it as PHP and downloads the source code)

Comment: Make sure nginx is setup to handle php.  Try running a different php script to test its behavior.

Comment: Nginx is def. set up to run php, but only in files with the extension of .php so I assume it is deciding that since the URI of this request is not ending in .php there is a problem

Comment: I needed to add fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;  in that block to get PHP to parse the files